# Disable the button if span not have class

Tags: javascript

I need to disabled button if span doesn't have a class "hide", and enabled if that have this class.

I can't change id of button, but can change class of button, and id and class of span

```
function myFunction() {
  if ($("#error-msg").hasClass("hide")){
  document.getElementByClassName("f-btn").disabled = false;
} else {
 document.getElementClassName("f-btn").disabled = true;

}}
```

```
<span id="error-msg" class="hide">Text</span>

<button class="f-btn">Try it</button>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName(...)[0].disabled`  You should be seeing an error in your console about your method usage.  You **should** be looking at your console.

Comment: There is no such thing as `getElementClassName`. However, there *is* [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Also as a side note, you don't need a full blown `if` statement.  just set the disabled to the `!(has class check)` logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelctor()` for select an element. You can try this-

```js
const span = document.querySelector('#error-msg');
const btn = document.querySelector('.f-btn');

if (span.classList.contains('hide')) {
 btn.disabled = false;
} else {
 btn.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<span id="error-msg" class="hide">Text</span>
<button class="f-btn">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Dont work....you can see that on this link http://514.weborob-it.com/

Comment: in console have "TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null"

Comment: Check the ```f-btn``` class exists. This is working here see running the code snippet.

Comment: yes. class exists and I see, snippet work...but on my forrm dont work(((

Comment: Do you use ```const``` for variable declaration?

Comment: Yes, I copy your code http://joxi.ru/J2bKXw9SGRvzXA but i have error in console "TypeError: btn is null"

Comment: Wrap the code by ```window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){//paste the code here})```

Comment: Okay, now button disabled, but thay disabled all time xD

Comment: The condition is if the ```span#error-msg``` has the class ```hide``` then the button is disabled. You have to remove the ```hide``` class from the element so that the button can be enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I made the mistake. The condition should be reversed.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try this now.

Comment: Dont work. Maybe we can use <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓</span>. This displayed if number is valid.

Comment: I don't know what your logic is. You can share what exactly you want. I think I can help you. :)

Comment: You have telegram or somthing lake that?

Comment: Nope. You can mail me. ```sajeeb07ahamed@gmail.com```

Comment: write you) my mail dklauey@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){
  if ($("#error-msg").hasClass("hide")){
  document.getElementsByClassName("f-btn")[0].disabled = false;
} else {
console.log('false');
 document.getElementsByClassName("f-btn")[0].disabled = true;

}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="error-msg"  class=>Text</span>

<button class="f-btn" onclick='myFunction()'>Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi here is your code some changes and its work when span have class "hide" disabled false

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<span id="error-msg" class="hide qdasd">Text</span>

<button class="f-btn" onclick='myFunction()'>Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var checkHide = document.getElementById("error-msg").classList.value

  if (checkHide.includes("hide")){
  document.getElementsByClassName("f-btn")[0].disabled = false;
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("f-btn"))
} else {
 document.getElementsClassName("f-btn")[0].disabled = true;

}}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```